# Username policy

Tags: discussion

I'm new to SO. I notice that there are many users with a username like user12345. Why is that? Are people picking these random names? Or does SO create incremental anonymous names?

Comment: SO creates default usernames and people are free to choose whatever they want.  Calling yourself a well-known _living_ personality might not appropriate, though.

Comment: Don't forget about anonymous users

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set a custom nickname than you have a user123456 nickname that's all. I guess that the number is the user id of each user if he/she has not set a custom nickname.

If you look at this random user you see that my guess is correct:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3582443/user3582443

For comparison here is your profile:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2992891/virushunter